# JavaCC multiline comment in custom NetBeans plugin

Tags: netbeans, javacc

I am having a problem with comments in creating custom file in NetBeans. I got two types of multiline comment types:

1. starting with `/*` and ending `*/`
2. starting with `<!--` and ending `-->`

`MORE :
{
  "/*": XSCRIPT_COMMENT
| 
  "<!--": XML_COMMENT
}`

`<XSCRIPT_COMMENT>
TOKEN :
{
  <X_SCRIPT_COMMENT_END: "*/" > : DEFAULT
}`

`<XML_COMMENT>
TOKEN :
{
  <XML_COMMENT_END: "-->" > : DEFAULT
}`

`<XSCRIPT_COMMENT,XML_COMMENT>
MORE :
{
  < ~[] >
}`

the problem is, that both multiline comments throws `TokenMgrError` when I write the initial part of comment (`/*` or `<!--`). The error occurs only when there is no ending part and lexer reaches end of file.

My goal is to create multiline comments which works similar to other comment types (When only initial part is written, the rest of document is comment type text).

Please excuse my english, not my native language.

Comment: Usually people have the opposite problem.  They use a single regular expression to match comments and then wonder why they get strange results when a multiline comment is not closed before the end of the file. The fix to their problem is to do what you've done above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a single regular expression to match comments.  For example a /* .. */
multiline comment can be matched by

```
"/*" (("*")* ~["*"])* ("*" ("*")* "/"?)?
```

Here I made the final "*/" optional. (The best way to come up with this sort of regular expression, in my experience, is to convert an NDFA to an RE, if you know how to do that.)

Another way to do it is to allow an empty string to end a comment. Add these two rules.

```
<XML_COMMENT> TOKEN : { <XML_COMMENT_END: "" > : DEFAULT }
<XSCRIPT_COMMENT> TOKEN : { <X_SCRIPT_COMMENT_END: "" > : DEFAULT }
```

Comment: By using regular expression instead of "MORE" will be created two more TOKENS. When used "MORE", there will be two new states instead of two TOKENS. What is better?

Comment: I think the two approaches produce the same sequence of tokens for each input sequence of characters.  Given a choice I prefer whichever approach is going to be easiest for the next person to understand.  That might be the lexical state approach.  Also, since I haven't tried it myself, I'm curious to know if it will work!

Answer (score 4):

For me, MartinZ's aswer also resolve an JavaCC lexical problem.

```
 { <COMMENT: "/*" (~["*"])* |  
             "/*" (~["*"])* "*" (~["/"])* |
             "/*" (~["*"])* "*" (~["/"])* "/" > }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by different regular expression. First I created deterministic automaton just with pen and paper, but graphic view is always the best.

```
<XSCRIPT_COMMENT:  
 "/*" (~["*"])* 
|
 "/*" (~["*"])* "*" (~["/"])*
| 
 "/*" (~["*"])* "*" (~["/"])* "/"
>

<XML_COMMENT:
 "<!--" (~["-"])*
|
 "<!--" (~["-"])* "-" (~["-"])*
|
 "<!--" (~["-"])* "-" (~["-"])* "-" (~[">"])*
|
 "<!--" (~["-"])* "-" (~["-"])* "-" (~[">"])* ">"
>
```

I realize that both expressions aren't from minimized DFA, but like this it is easier to understand.

Comment: Wouldn't this recognize `/*a*b/`?  And would it recognize `/*a*b*c`? You are using the right approach, but I'm not sure you are getting the right result.  This illustrates one point in favour of lexical states: when you know what the DFA is, you can just tell JavaCC what it is and not have to calculate some complex regular expression.